# Why should we prefer table over div when it comes to emailers?

Tags: html, email, table

When it comes to converting designed email templates to html format, how is a table layout better than a div? What are the exact reasons we tend to choose table over div for emailers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[nathangiesbrecht](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/15209/nathangiesbrecht) said in comments:

Mostly because many e-mail clients have really lousy support for modern HTML. While table-based layouts are incredibly old-school, most e-mail clients will display them properly. You also want to keep your CSS all in-line as many e-mail clients strip out any other CSS (think web e-mail clients, and the problems an e-mail could cause if they loaded CSS files).

[Using basic inline styling for divs] might make a bit of a difference, but likely not enough. The problem lies in the HTML rendering engines used by many E-mail clients. For example, Microsoft Outlook uses the Microsoft Word HTML engine for rendering, and it's quite bad. You can also checkout http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/email-marketing-field-guide for more e-mail best practices. It's a pretty comprehensive guide.